# Nuxt.js and axios don't work with Express server

Tags: mysql, localhost, axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to make a like system using Nuxt.js and MySQL but it don't work.

There is my component for describe a post with the like button

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post-details">
        {{ id }}
    </div>
    <div class="post-content">
        {{ content }}
        <form @submit.prevent="like">
            <button type="submit" class="likes">
                <i class='fas fa-heart'></i> 
                {{ likes_count }} 
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        props: ['id', 'content', 'likes'],
        data() {
            return {
                post_id: this.id,
                likes_count: 0
            }
        },
        methods: {
            like() {
                axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/like', this.post_id) 
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res)
                    this.likes_count++
                }).catch(res => {
                    console.log(res)
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And my route for update database and increase like column

```
app.post('/api/like', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.body.id
    database.query("UPDATE posts SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE id = ?"), [id], (err, rows) => {
        if(err) console.log(err)
        if(rows.affectedRows != 0) console.log(rows.affectedRows)
        res.json(rows)
    })
})
```

What is the problem ? Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the problem? Exactly. What _is_ your problem? Describe what you see. Tell us what results you get. Quote relevant server logs. Show your research.

Answer (score 0):

At first look: POST request params should be an object

```
axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/like', {id: this.post_id})
```

And yes, you should show error logs (client and server) to get any help here.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I change put verb by post and it works !

I start with Nuxt and I'm not really comfortable with api, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
data() {
  return {
    form {
      post_id: this.id,
      likes_count: 0
    }
  }
}

axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/like', this.form)
```